# For loop with conditions

Tags: linux, shell-script, perl, bash-scripting

I have a script that adds user on many server. Since I'm adding on many server(s) I am using for loop.

Below are the output when user is successfully added.

```
0,22529,User added.
```

If the user is not added, then I get this error

```
1,23996,CLI failed to connect to database.
```

OR

```
1,22560,The current state of the server does not allow this action.
```

---

```
script Begin

read user
echo -e '\E[32;40m'"\033[1mPlease wait .... adding id on all server\033[0m"
PORT=777
USER=User
PASSWORD=****
for server in server1.abc.com server2.abc.com 
do
command // to add user 
done

Script end
```

I want echo of both user added and user not added based on server list passed for loop.

Eg.

```
User added in server1.abc.com
user failed to add in server2.abc.com
```

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the standard output of a certain command, you can use [command substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html) and wrap it inside a `$(…)`.

We can check if the output conforms to a certain regular expression with the `=~` operator introduced in Bash 3 and above. If the regular expression matches, the test will return true, so we can execute another command after `&&`. If it doesn't match, the test will return false, and the commands after `||` are executed.

Since we want to check whether the output contains the word `added`, the following is enough:

```
for server in server1.abc.com server2.abc.com 
do
  [[ "$(command)" =~ added ]] \
    && echo "User ${user} added in ${server}" \
    || echo "User ${user} failed to add in ${server}"
done
```

In your script you should change `USER` to `user`, since `$USER` is a global environment variable carrying your username. Try running `echo $USER` from your command line to see what I mean.

Comment: yes, it is generally advised to use lower case variable names, so you don't accidentally overwrite bash variables.

Comment: You're welcome, @maneeshshetty. Did you know the Super User way of saying "thank you" is voting up answers you found useful? I see you haven't cast any votes yet. Just click the up vote arrow next to their score. It just takes a second – but this way you'll pay it forward to others.

Comment: I didn't knew this, I just did that! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
for server in ...; do
    command | while IFS=, read exitstatus id message; do
        if [[ $exitstatus == "0" ]]; then
            echo "User added on $server"
        else
            echo "Failed to add user on $server: $message"
        fi
    done
done
```

However, check the actual exit status of `command` -- does it return a non-zero exit status for failure?

```
for server in ...; do
    if output=$(command); then
        echo "User added on $server"
    else
        echo "Failed to add user on $server: $output"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Hadn't thought of using `read` and assigning the variables there, nice one.